# Accessing NASA api using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

So I'm new to using Javascript and I'm wondering how to access NASA API such as https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/earth/assets?lon=100.75&lat=1.5&begin=2014-02-01&api_key=DEMO_KEY
and using the data? I want to get the "dates" and put them into an array, but I don't know how to do that. How can I do this using Javascript?

Comment: maybe the code in [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38881388/javascript-http-request-failed) will help

Answer (score 1):

if you are using jQuery, you can do an ajax call using the jQuery.ajax( url ) method and passing in 'https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/earth/assets?lon=100.75&lat=1.5&begin=2014-02-01&api_key=DEMO_KEY' as the url.

EDIT: this is more detailed code/explaination fodoing an ajax request in jquery:

```
$.ajax({

    // The URL for the request
    url: "https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/earth/assets?lon=100.75&lat=1.5&begin=2014-02-01&api_key=DEMO_KEY",


    // Whether this is a POST or GET request
    type: "GET",

    // The type of data we expect back
    dataType : "json",
})
  // Code to run if the request succeeds (is done);
  // The response is passed to the function
  .done(function( json ) {
     console.log(json)
  })
  // Code to run if the request fails; the raw request and
  // status codes are passed to the function
  .fail(function( xhr, status, errorThrown ) {
    alert( "Sorry, there was a problem!" );
    console.log( "Error: " + errorThrown );
    console.log( "Status: " + status );
    console.dir( xhr );
  })
  // Code to run regardless of success or failure;
  .always(function( xhr, status ) {
    alert( "The request is complete!" );
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Read [this guide from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started) about Ajax. Then you can use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to parse the returned data, and then [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get the dates from each item in the results array. See the example below. If you want to use a library like [jQuery](https://jquery.org) then the AJAX code will be simplified.

```js
var url = 'https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/earth/assets?lon=100.75&lat=1.5&begin=2014-02-01&api_key=DEMO_KEY';
var httpRequest; //declare here for good scope
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, IE7+ ...
  httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE 6 and older
  httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (httpRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && httpRequest.status == 200) {
    returnedData = httpRequest.responseText;
    var data = JSON.parse(returnedData);
    if (data.hasOwnProperty('results')) {
      var dates = data.results.map(function(result) {
        return result.date;
        });
      console.log('dates: ',dates);
     }
  } else {
    // still not ready or error occurred
  }
};
httpRequest.open('GET', url, true);
httpRequest.send(null);
```

Comment: To understand well what this code is doing you will want to understand [callbacks in JavaScript](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/), and if you want to write clean async code using modern patterns you should try to understand and use [JavaScript promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).  Callbacks/promises are necessary because you don't know exactly how long an http request will take to return it's data.  They're a way to say "Do this as soon as you get a response.".

Comment: Thanks for the resources @Skylar - though it should be noted that some browsers (mostly IE) don't support Promises natively (refer to the [Browser Compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Browser_compatibility) section) so if one had to support customers using any of those older browsers they should adjust accordingly. I also recommend reading this [Functional Programming in JS page](http://reactivex.io/learnrx/) (and completing the exercises), which also mentions asynchronous code and callbacks (mostly exercises 34-5)

Comment: A colleague also shared with me http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/ - if you want to use promises without adding all of the overhead of jQuery, [reqwest](https://github.com/ded/Reqwest) and [then-request](https://github.com/then/then-request) look _promising_ (sorry I had to)... I mean they look like good options

Answer (score 0):

Try to use it like this, with jquery:

```
var array = [];
$.get('https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/earth/assets?lon=100.75&lat=1.5&begin=2014-02-01&api_key=DEMO_KEY',function(data){
       for(var i=0; i< data.results.length; i++) {
        array.push(data.results[i].date);
       }
    console.log(array);
});
```

Then in console you can see the result. Or just use the array variable for your needs

Comment: How am I able to use the dates? Like add or subtract two dates?

Comment: you may access the data with index - array[i] - where i is index. Or search the array for the needed value. I don't know what do you currently need. Too add a data to array - array.push(data) - it will add to the end of array